# Solving Integral Equation -numerical solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to find a (numerical) solution to the following integral equation:

[image]

where $\epsilon$ is a real valued function and $\beta$ and $c_0$ are constants.

MMA code:

```
-(β*Integrate[ϵ[s]/E^((-s + t)*β), {s, 0, t}]) + β*Integrate[ϵ[s]^2/E^((-s + t)*β), {s, 0, t}] + 
β*Integrate[(ϵ[s]^2*ϵ[t])/E^((-s + t)*β), {s, 
0, t}] + ϵ[t] - ϵ[t]^2 == c0
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code for the expression in the image.

Comment: What is the value of `c0`? Or are you looking for an analytical solution?

Comment: One point I don't understand: The integral equation holds for every t, especially `t==0` . Because `\[Epsilon][0]==0` it follows `c0==0`! If yes, the fixpointiteration yields `\[Epsilon][t]==0` !

Comment: @ Ulrich, My bad, you are right. [Epsilon][0] is not zero. I removed that from the post. c_0 is a positive number. Thank you!

Comment: @Klaas-Jan Thanks for correction. I'm still waiting and hoping for a numerical answer to your question. 'til now only "@AlexTrounev" tried a numerical answer

Comment: @Ulrich, have you checked Akku14's method shown below? I am looking at it right now and it looks pretty good.

Comment: @Jan-Klaas Thanks for the hint. I checked  the answer, wonder why the time range is very small  (t<<5) and the solution doesn't match cesaro's analytic solution( `\[Beta]==1,c0==.2`?

Comment: @Jan-Klaas See my answer for a straightforward numerical solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the integral equation into a second order differential equation and solve with NDSolve.

Multiply the equation with E^(beta*t) and bring it to one side to get feq. Differentiate two times and eliminate the remaining integral. Get initial conditions.

```
feq = (-c0)*E^(t*\[Beta]) - \[Beta]*
Integrate[E^(s*\[Beta])*\[Epsilon][s], 
       {s, 0, t}] + \[Beta]*
Integrate[E^(s*\[Beta])*\[Epsilon][s]^2, {s, 0, t}] + 
   \[Beta]*\[Epsilon][t]*
Integrate[E^(s*\[Beta])*\[Epsilon][s]^2, {s, 0, t}] + 
   E^(t*\[Beta])*\[Epsilon][t] - E^(t*\[Beta])*\[Epsilon][t]^2; 

dfeq = D[feq, t]

d2feq = D[dfeq, t]

eli[t_, \[Beta]_, c0_] = Simplify[Eliminate[{dfeq == 0, d2feq == 0}, 
   Integrate[E^(s*\[Beta])*\[Epsilon][s]^2, {s, 0, t}]]]

{{ic1a[c0_]}, {ic1b[c0_]}} = Solve[feq == 0 /. t -> 0, \[Epsilon][0]]

ic2a[\[Beta]_, c0_] = 
  Solve[dfeq == 0 /. t -> 0 /. ic1a[c0], \[Epsilon]'[0]][[1, 1]]

ic2b[\[Beta]_, c0_] = 
  Solve[dfeq == 0 /. t -> 0 /. ic1b[c0], \[Epsilon]'[0]][[1, 1]]    

\[Epsilon]sola[\[Beta]_, c0_] := \[Epsilon] /. 
   First@NDSolve[{eli[t, \[Beta], c0], Equal @@ ic1a[c0], 
 Equal @@ ic2a[\[Beta], c0]}, \[Epsilon], {t, 0, 20}]

\[Epsilon]solb[\[Beta]_, c0_] := \[Epsilon] /. 
   First@NDSolve[{eli[t, \[Beta], c0], Equal @@ ic1b[c0], 
 Equal @@ ic2b[\[Beta], c0]}, \[Epsilon], {t, 0, 20}]

Manipulate[{Plot[
Evaluate[(aa = \[Epsilon]sola[\[Beta], c0])[t]], {t, 
 0, .99*aa[[1, 1, 2]]}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
ImageSize -> 300] // Quiet, 
Plot[Evaluate[(aa = \[Epsilon]solb[\[Beta], c0])[t]], {t, 
 0, .99*aa[[1, 1, 2]]}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
ImageSize -> 300] // Quiet}, {{\[Beta], .1}, -3, 3, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, -.5}, -3, 1/4, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Test: Show that one sided equation is very close to zero. Takes a few minutes. (Even better with higher WorkingPrecision of NDSolve and NIntegrate).

```
ff[t_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_, c0_] = 
  feq /. \[Epsilon] -> (aa = \[Epsilon]sola[.1, -.5]); pl = 
Plot[ff[t, .1, -.5] /. Integrate -> NIntegrate, {t, 0, 
aa[[1, 1, 2]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I checked your solution with `\[Beta] -> 1, c0 -> .2` but NDSolve gives a warning message "NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 0.3874777341671869`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." and stops evaluation. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i think for certain parameters the integral equation does not hold for larger t values. See also my comment to your answer. You may get the same termination at higher t for certain beta, c0 with my proposed change of nested equation.

Answer (score 5):

An iterative approach based on the fixed point existence.

$$
\epsilon_{k+1}(t)=\Phi\left(\epsilon_{k}(t),t\right)
$$

```
f = c0;
sols = {f}
n = 9;
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
 Clear[ϵ];
 ϵ[t_] := f;
 f = (β*Integrate[ϵ[s]/E^((t - s)*β), {s, 0, t}]) - β*Integrate[ϵ[s]^2/E^((t - s)*β), {s, 0, t}] - β*ϵ[t]*Integrate[(ϵ[s]^2)/E^((t- s)*β), {s, 0, t}] + ϵ[t]^2 + c0;
 AppendTo[sols, f]
]

parms = {c0 -> 0.2, β -> 1};
funcs = sols /. parms;
Plot[funcs, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

As a checking the convergence

```
ϵ[t_] := funcs[[n+1]];
dif = (β*Integrate[ϵ[s]/E^((t - s)*β), {s, 0, t}]) - β*Integrate[ϵ[s]^2/E^((t - s)*β), {s, 0, t}] - β*ϵ[t]*Integrate[(ϵ[s]^2)/E^((t- s)*β), {s, 0, t}] + ϵ[t]^2 + c0 - ϵ[t];

Plot[dif, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And now follows a layman solution (second order splines) to this problem.

```
fl[a_, b_, c_, delta_, t_, n_] := Sum[(UnitStep[t - k delta] - UnitStep[t - (k + 1) delta]) (a[k] + b[k] (t - k delta) + c[k] (t - k delta)^2), {k, 0, n}]

n = 40;
tmax = 10;
delta = tmax/n;
fl0 = fl[a, b, c, delta, t, n];
For[k = n - 1, k >= 0, k--,
  fl0 = fl0 /. {a[k + 1] -> a[k] + delta b[k] + delta^2 c[k], b[k + 1] -> b[k] + 2 delta c[k]}]
vars = Join[{a[0], b[0]}, Table[c[k], {k, 0, n}]];

Clear[ϵ]
ϵ[t_] := fl0;
dif = (β*Integrate[ϵ[s]/E^((t - s)*β), {s, 0, t}]) - β*Integrate[ϵ[s]^2/E^((t - s)*β), {s, 0, t}] - β*ϵ[t]*Integrate[(ϵ[s]^2)/E^((t- s)*β), {s, 0, t}] - ϵ[t] + ϵ[t]^2 + c0;

parms = {c0 -> 0.20, β -> 0.2};
dif0 = dif /. parms;
points = Table[dif0, {t, 0, tmax, delta/2}];
npts = Length[points];
diag = Table[(npts - k + 1), {k, 1, npts}];
obj = points.DiagonalMatrix[diag].points;
sol = NMinimize[obj, vars, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
sol[[1]]
et = fl0 /. sol[[2]];
Plot[et, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

[image]

NOTE

Also at $t=0$ we have

```
ϵ[0]^2 - ϵ[0] + c0 == 0
```

so for $c_0\lt \frac 14$ two $\epsilon[0]$ are feasible, suggesting that two branches are allowed.

Comment: Can we done with `NIntegrate` not `Integrate` ,because is very slow?

Comment: With Integrate we obtain a parametric solution.

Comment: try `FixedPointList`

Comment: @Cesareo It is nice code (+1). But you did not pay attention there are two branch of solution.

Comment: @Cesaro. Thanks, the last term on the rhs of "f" function. It should be +c_0 not -c_0, right?

Comment: @Klaas-Jan Tanks for the tip,

Comment: @Cesaro Please check your code, possibly you should change `ϵ[s_] := f` to `ϵ[t_] := f` ! If yes this could be the reason why your `analytic solution` doesn't match my `numerical solution`(see my answer). Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I introduced some modifications but the result seems to be the almost same.

Comment: @Cesareo, you say "Note that the initial condition for ϵ′(0) was reduced to be solved."  You can not choose initial conditions as you like. For given beta and c0 they are fixed by `sol = Solve[eq0 /. t -> 0, \[Epsilon][0]] /. c0 -> .2 ` to `{{\[Epsilon][0] -> 0.276393}, {\[Epsilon][0] -> 0.723607}} `  and `Solve[D[eq0, t] /. t -> 0 /. sol[[1]], \[Epsilon]'[0]] /. {\[Beta] -> 
   1, c0 -> .2} ` to `{{Derivative[1][\[Epsilon]][0] -> 0.4}} ` . With that, you get (like me) that solution explodes for t > 0.387, means integral equation does not hold anymore for larger t.

Comment: As i said to @UlrichNeumann, you get better result for the iteration process, if you don't have eps[t] in the iterated function but only eps[s]. Therefore use `sol = Solve[-(\[Beta]*        Integrate[\[Epsilon][s]/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0,           t}]) + \[Beta]*      Integrate[\[Epsilon][s]^2/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0,         t}] + \[Beta]*\[Epsilon][       t] Integrate[(\[Epsilon][s]^2)/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0,         t}] + \[Epsilon][t] - \[Epsilon][t]^2 == c0, \[Epsilon][t]]  `

Comment: There is a fundamental change for c0 from 0.15 to 0 .2. If you choose c0 ==0.15 you get non exploding curve for t < 5 (with my solution function) `Plot[Evaluate[\[Epsilon]sola[1, .15][t]], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All,
   GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300] // Quiet `

Comment: @Cesareo I'm still sure that the definition `ϵ1[s_] := f` makes no sense because `s` is the integration variable! Try ` f = Module[{s},(β*Integrate[...` to see that `f` doesn't depend on s.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this equation using colocation method and Haar wavelets.  There are two branch of solution for every $c0 < 1/2$. For some $\beta, c0$ we can get these branches with code

```
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
plot[cc_, bb_, rr_, nn_] := 
 Module[{c0 = cc, b = bb, r = rr, n = nn}, 
  M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; 
  dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; 
  xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
  psi1[x_] := WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], x]; 
  psi2[x_] := WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x]; 
  psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k]; 
  psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k]; 
  psijk[x_, j_, k_] := Sqrt[j]*(psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k]); 
  np = M; gw = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1]; 
  points = gw[[All, 1]]; weights = gw[[All, 2]];
  GaussInt[ff_, z_] := 
   Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]; 
  u[t_] := Sum[
     a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    a0 + 1/2 + r Sqrt[1/4 - c0]; 
  u[t_] := Sum[
     a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    a0 + 1/2 + r Sqrt[1/4 - c0]; 
  varM = Join[{a0}, 
    Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
  int1[t_] := (t/
      2) GaussInt[(1 + z) u[t/2 (z + 1)] Exp[((-t/2 (1 + z) + t)*b)], 
     z](*s\[Rule]x/2 (1+z)*);
  int2[t_] := (t/
      2) GaussInt[(1 + z) u[
        t/2 (z + 1)]^2 Exp[((-t/2 (1 + z) + t)*b)], z]; 
  varM = Join[{a0}, 
    Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
  int1[t_] := (t/
      2) GaussInt[(1 + z) u[t/2 (z + 1)] Exp[((-t/2 (1 + z) + t)*b)], 
     z](*s\[Rule]x/2 (1+z)*);
  int2[t_] := (t/
      2) GaussInt[(1 + z) u[
        t/2 (z + 1)]^2 Exp[((-t/2 (1 + z) + t)*b)], z];
  eq = Table[
    u[t] - u[t]^2 - b int1[t] + b int2[t] + b u[t] int2[t] - c0 == 
     0, {t, xcol}]; 
  sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{varM[[i]], r/10}, {i, Length[varM]}], 
    MaxIterations -> 1000];
  unum = Table[ {xcol[[i]], Evaluate[u[xcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, 
     Length[xcol]}]; ListLinePlot[unum]]
```

Here $u=\epsilon, b=\beta$, $n$ is number of colocation points and $r=\pm 1$ is the indicator of branch. For example, for $c0=-0.5, \beta =0.1$ we have

```
{plot[-.5, 0.1, -1, 4], plot[-.5, 0.1, 1, 4]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I tried with: `c0 = -0.2; \[Beta] = 1;`.The Plot is different than from answer from user @Cesareo ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk First please pay attention that wavelets  solution is defined on $0\le t\le 1$. Also this solution not stable with $\beta =1$. You may try to compare my example  with Cesareo.

Answer (score 2):

Waiting some time for a straightforward numerical answer, here my attempt, which assumes  `\[Beta] = 1` (without loss of generality) and predefined values `c0==0.2,T0==5` :

```
c0 = 2/10; T = 5;
gip[eps_] :=Module[{x, t}, 
Interpolation[Table[{t,eps[t]^2 + c0 + Exp[-t] NIntegrate[eps[s] Exp[s], {s, 0, t}] -Exp[-t] (1 + eps[t]) NIntegrate[eps[s]^2 Exp[s], {s, 0, t}]}, {t, Subdivide[0, T, 25]}]]]
```

Function `gip` get's a pure function as input argument and returns an InterpolationFunction, which might be used iteratively.

With appropriate starting value `eps[0]== 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c0])` (second solution branch `eps[0]== 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c0]) omitted` ) it follows

```
solm = NestList[gip, 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c0]) &, 15] ;
Plot[Evaluate[Through[solm [t]]], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image]

The solution doesn't match completely @cesaro's one (shows superimposed oscillations). Perhaps it shows a first step for a completely numerical solution.

To exclude the influence of simple `Interpolation` I also tried a numerical solution using `NDSolveValue` (substitution `i1[t]==Integrate[eps[s]Exp[s],{s,0,t}]` and `i2[t]==Integrate[eps[s]^2 Exp[s],{s,0,t}]`) :

```
ff = Function[{t}, 
NDSolveValue[{i1'[t] == #[t] Exp[t], i1[0] == 0,
i2'[t] == #[t]^2 Exp[t], i2[0] == 0},
#[t]^2 + c0 + Exp[-t] (i1[t] - (1 + #[t]) i2[t]) 
, {t, 0,T}, DependentVariables -> {i1, i2}
,Method -> {Automatic ,"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False  },AccuracyGoal -> 10 ]] & ;
```

which gives the same result(I used only 7 iterations because of increased evaluation time):

```
sol = NestList[ff, 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 c0]) &, 7]; // AbsoluteTiming 
Plot[Evaluate[Through[sol[t]]], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image]

**conclusion**

The two numerical solutions, obtained with two independent methods, match very well. I'm quite convinced that the solutions describe the iteration of the given integral equation.

Hints for improvement are welcome!

Comment: Dear @UlrichNeumann, up to now this solutions give the wrong derivative at t ==0 and bad equ test. If you  solve the whole equation for eps[t], like `sol = Solve[-(\[Beta]*
       Integrate[\[Epsilon][s]/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0, 
         t}]) + \[Beta]*
     Integrate[\[Epsilon][s]^2/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0, 
       t}] + \[Beta]*\[Epsilon][
      t] Integrate[(\[Epsilon][s]^2)/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0, 
       t}] + \[Epsilon][t] - \[Epsilon][t]^2 == c0, \[Epsilon][t]] ` you get two branches. Making nested iteration with that, your code gives very simular solutions to mine.

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks for your reply. I'll check your hint . Because the iterated integraleequation (in my approach) doesn't depend on the derivative `eps'[t]` I still have doubts.

Comment: @Akku14 I dont't think, that it's allowed to solve the Integral equation for `\[Epsilon][t]` , thereby ignoring the parts  `\[Epsilon][s]` . This is only allowed for `t==0` and gives the two initial conditions depending on `c0`. In my answer I only showed the solution for the first ic, the second follows similar.

Comment: To @UlrichNeumann  You didn't understand me right. I never wanted to solve the int equation this way. Produce gip2 like `c0 = -.5; T = 20; \[Beta] = .1;  gip2[eps_] := `

Comment: `Module[{x, t}, 
 Interpolation[
  Table[{t, (1/
       2)*(1 + \[Beta]*Exp[-t \[Beta]] NIntegrate[E^((s)*\[Beta])*
                   eps[s]^2, {s, 0, t}] - 
             Sqrt[1 - 4*c0 - 4*\[Beta]*Exp[-t \[Beta]] NIntegrate[
                     E^((s )*\[Beta])*eps[s], {s, 0, t}] + 
                 
         6*\[Beta]*
          Exp[-t \[Beta]] NIntegrate[E^((s )*\[Beta])*eps[s]^2, 
                     {s, 0, t}] + \[Beta]^2*Exp[-t \[Beta]] 
                   NIntegrate[E^((s)*\[Beta])*eps[s]^2, 
                       {s, 0, t}]^2])}, {t, 0, T, T/24}]]]  `

Comment: and compare it with my solution `solm = NestList[gip2, 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c0]) &, 5];
pl = Plot[
  Evaluate[{solm[[5]][t], \[Epsilon]sola[.1, -.5][t]}], {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, Red}] `

Comment: @Akku14 Thank you for your reply, I have to find time to check it...

Comment: @Akku14 How can I find the context of `gip2[eps]` and the iterated integral equation? Thanks.

Comment: gip2[eps_] := Module[{x, t},   Interpolation[.....    Just combine ( was too long for one comment) my last 3 comments and copy and paste the code from my answer and start it once to get \[Epsilon]sola.

Comment: @Akku14 That's clear, my question concerns the derivation of the formula and the context to the original integral equation.

Comment: As i wrote above in my first comment, just solve the original integral equation of the OP for eps[t]  `sol = Solve[-(\[Beta]*        Integrate[\[Epsilon][s]/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0,           t}]) + \[Beta]*      Integrate[\[Epsilon][s]^2/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0,         t}] + \[Beta]*\[Epsilon][       t] Integrate[(\[Epsilon][s]^2)/E^((-s + t)*\[Beta]), {s, 0,         t}] + \[Epsilon][t] - \[Epsilon][t]^2 == c0, \[Epsilon][t]]  ` You didn't read that?

Comment: @Akku14 I did, see my 2. comment "I don't think…"